# What is the buyandsell strategy?

Tags: strategy

I have read such codes as below in [buyandsell strategy](https://www.qmr.ai/building-a-backtesting-framework-in-python-from-scratch/)

```
from backtesting import Backtest, Strategy

class BuyAndSellSwitch(Strategy):
    def init(self):
        pass
    def next(self):
        if self.position.size == 0:
            self.buy(size=1)
        else:
            self.sell(size=1)

bt = Backtest(data, BuyAndSellSwitch, cash=10000)
output = bt.run()
output
```

What does the strategy mean on earth?

Comment: The link you posted looks like it's more about the task of building a *framework* to backtest strategies, as opposed to coming up with any "good" strategies. The BuyAndSellSwitch you posted looks to be a very simple strategy, likely only implemented for the purposes of testing code, that buys 1 unit if we have no units, and then sells 1 unit if we have 1 unit (in other words, buys then sells then buys then sells then buys then sells then...)

Comment: For example if I want to calculate the P&L from buying MSFT on date1 and selling it on date2, I would just call *buyandsell* on these 2 dates. A very simple code which might be useful to someone.

Comment: "buy low, sell high";{)}